# Which library should i download to read JSON in C# on Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, json, dll

I am trying to download library to parse JSON on C# on Windows Phone 8. I am working with visual studio 2013. The library files that I have found online does not work with windows phone 8. May I know if there are any online libraries that I may have overlook?

Comment: Perhaps at least naming the library you have tried, or showing your code might allow others to help you. Currently your question is very vague http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [Json.net](http://json.codeplex.com/)
The site says that it supports windows phone 8. This package could be downloaded from Nuget.

Hope it helps. Thanks